# I am trying to send characters via Bluetooth using an android app but it's not able to send anything. Do you know what's wrong?

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I am using a Bluefruit Module and Android Studio. I am trying to send data from the app on my android table to the Bluefruit Module. We are using MatLab to check when characters are being received. Here is the code I am using for just the send capability. I can include more if needed.

```
btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                finalValue = String.valueOf((char)(val + offset + 97));
                byte[] bytes = etSend.getText().toString().getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
                mBluetoothConnection.write(bytes);
            }
        });
```

I uploaded the entire app code to the tablet. The tablet is able to connect with the bluetooth module but it does not send any characters.

Comment: Consider adding the all relevant code. As far as I know the [Bluefruit module](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2479) is a Bluetooth Low Energy capable module. But you try to send data using Bluetooth Classic API of Android. You have to use Bluetooth LE API in order to send and get data. That's why you better add your whole implementation code for us to be able to analyze the issues.